# Bash script check permissions to run command on remote

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a local development machine and from my bash script am sending commands to the remote server.

**How can I write bash code to check if I am allowed to run the remote command so that I can handle the success/failure response from my script?**

Alternatively, how can I capture the output so that I can parse it and detect if it succeeded. The difficulty with parsing is that the ssh command might trigger a password prompt so I can't interfere with that.

That bash script uses `ssh -qt` to send the remote commands

**Command**

```
ssh user@host -qt "sudo -u www /usr/local/bin/php /mnt/data/script.php"
```

**Output:**

```
[sudo] password for xxx:
Sorry, user xxx is not allowed to execute '/usr/local/bin/php /mnt/data/script.php' as www on host.domain.com
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `user != root` above:  you can't - there's no way to read `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/*` in a **normally** set-up Linux box if you're not root, so apart from trial & error there's nothing to be done.

As for capturing the result - that's fairly simple (parsing it, of course, is a different story, depending on what you're doing over there).

```
output=$( ssh user@host -qt "sudo -u www /usr/local/bin/php /mnt/data/script.php" 2>&1 )
```

After the execution (and you typing the password for `sudo`)

```
echo $?      # gives you the return-code of what happened on the far end, if it's a success that should be 0
echo $output # gives you the strings to parse
```